# I've lost both of my APN .p8 key files, Is it possible to revoke one and create new?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apn, p8

I've both of my APN .p8 files, but now I can't create more as the limit of this key is 2. Is it possible to revoke the current key and then create another one? I don't want to take the risk of trying it out before any confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, in case you revoke the old one and create a new APNs .p8 file, there is only one problem: you must re-integrate on the server side with this new key. This new key has the same `Team ID` and `Bunle ID` but a different `Key ID`.

You also don't need to release a new build, use this new `.p8` file on server side, and that's it.

However, I think you should create a new key first, test it around a couple times, then revoke, for safety.

Comment: I can't create a new one before revoking one because a maximum of 2 keys can be created and I already have 2.

Comment: Ok, then do not delete both keys at the same time, safety first.